# The type checker doesn't like callable objects implementing noSuchMethod

Tags: dart

The following code works:

```dart
typedef num MyFunc(num);

class ObjectThatIsLikeFunc {
  call(x) => x;
}

var obj = new ObjectThatIsLikeFunc();
MyFunc g = obj; //works
```

If, however, ObjectThatIsLikeFunc doesn't have the call method, but defines noSuchMethod instead, it doesn't work.

```dart
typedef num MyFunc(num);

class ObjectThatIsLikeFunc {
  noSuchMethod(InvocationMirror) => 100;
}
```

I'm getting "is not a subtype of type 'MyFunc'".

My Question:
Is there a way to tell the type checker that ObjectThatIsLikeFunc with noSuchMethod can act as MyFunc?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, not that I'm aware of. The generalized case is, "how can I have a class that implements noSuchMethod act like any type?" I think I heard some talk of how Dart might allow this, but I couldn't find a reference to it.